# Add private key to production certificate for iOS

Tags: ios

The account owner has a production certificate that when I download and open shows in my key chain under "Certificates" but not under "My Certificates."  Therefore I cannot resign the .ipa.  Also, it does not have my private key attached to it.

How do I add my private key to it?  This is for an In House app distribution and I do not have the permissions to create a new "Production Certification" which should not be needed anyway.

Every thing is fine when I use a "Development Certificate."

Answer (score 0):

In order to attach a new private key, you will need permission to create a new certificate. If you get the original private key, you should be able to install that on your computer to resolve this problem without the need to create a new certificate.